# Vue.js does not display value on html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I really don't know what to do about it.

I'll try to explain:
I need to output value "senderName" in block of chat. For it, iteration over the arrays is used on mounted method. There are successfully output in console and Vue debagger extension, but the field for name is empty.If you enter text instead of the {{}} template, then everything is displayed.

**This is html code**

```
            <div
              v-for="chat in chats"
              :key="chat.id"
              @click="changeChat(chat.private_chat_id)"
              class="card chat-chart"
              style="
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 1px;
                box-shadow: none;
                border: 1px solid #eee;
              "
            >
              <div
                class="card-body mt--3"
                style="
                  height: 100px !important;
                  padding: 0.8rem i !important;
                "
              >
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <span class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle">
                      <img
                        src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                        alt="avatar"
                      />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-8 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <h4 class="card-title align-self-center mb-0">
                      {{ chat.senderName }}
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="row align-items-center justify-content-end mt--4 mb-4"
                  style="height: 1px"
                >
                  <div
                    v-if="chat.unreadCount > 0"
                    class="d-inline-block rounded-circle bg-success text-light ml-2 p-1"
                    style="
                      color: white !important;
                      font-weight: bold;
                      width: 30px;
                      height: 30px;
                    "
                  >
                    <!-- <p
                        class="text-center font-weight-bold"
                        style="line-height: 1.4"
                      >
                        {{ (chat.unreadCount > 99) ? 99 : chat.unreadCount
                        }}
                      </p> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="row align-items-center justify-content-start ml-1"
                >
                  <p>chat.msg</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**And here mounted method**

```
    mounted() {
      // Get all chats for user with id - userId
      axios
        .get("/api/users/" + this.userId + "/privatechat")
        .then((res) => {
          appChats.chats = res.data;
          // console.log(this.chats);

          // Itereate array of user's private chats
          for (let i = 0; i <= res.data.length; i++) {
            if (!res.data[i]) {
              continue;
            } else {
              // console.log(res.data[i]);
              let chatObj = res.data[i];
              // Get info of the chat with its id
              axios
                .get("/api/privatechat/" + chatObj.private_chat_id)
                .then((response) => {
                  // console.log(response.data);

                  for (values of response.data) {
                    // If user's id of the chat equals id of our user then skip
                    if (values.user_id == appChats.userId) continue;
                    else {
                      // console.log(values.user_id);
                      appChats.chats[i]["senderId"] = values.user_id;

                      // Get userName of our interlocutor
                      axios
                        .get("/api/users/" + values.user_id)
                        .then((r) => {
                          appChats.chats[i]["senderName"] =
                            r.data[0].username;
                        });
                    }
                  }
                });
            }
          }
        });
    },
```

There are some pics:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ejEU.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VFBv.png  // this pic is about Vue js extension

Comment: I think Vue doesn't detect value changed in this case (refs: [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats))

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] like codesandbox with dummy data?

Comment: as i am looking you have assigned "chats" into appChats.chats, but you have used "chats" in vue template, and you did not assign response into "chats" (ex: this.chats=response, or anything else) in mount block. so check that i think that will solve the issue. if you want more clarification then share the data block as well then i shall be able to give you more specific answer.

Comment: I am going to try rewrite code with reactivity. Thanks @IFZR